# My font shows up in the font list, but the document won't compile?

Tags: fonts, xetex, lyx

I'm using Lyx. I've got XeTex installed, and I downloaded a futura font clone. I installed it using the font viewer. OpenOffice can see and use it. However, when I go into Lyx to the following path

> Document->Settings->Fonts

and choose "Use non-TeX fonts (via XeTex/LuaTeX)" and "Futura Lt BT" from the list, it won't compile. Instead, it will give

`fontspec error: "font-not-found`

`Font \EU2/FuturaLtBT(0)/m/n/10=FuturaLtBT:mode=node;+tlig;+trep; at 10pt not l`

I've made sure the font is in a directory with the other truetype fonts, in a custom file.

Mimimum code which produces the error output looks like

```
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\language english
\font_roman Futura Lt BT
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true

\graphics default
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
Test
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide the code which gives the error in the form of a minimal non-working example i.e. a complete but minimal document. You can either provide `.tex` or `.lyx`. `.tex` will be usable by more potential helpers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Using lyx requires no code. The only command required is 'ctr-r' to generate the document. Instead of creating a PDF, it brings up the above error.

Comment: LyX hides the code from you, but it is still there. We need to see the code which produces the error. Make the smallest document you can which gives the error and then either post the `.lyx` file or, preferably, the `.tex` equivalent. I'm not talking about the code to compile - that is just running `xelatex` or `lualatex` or whatever. It is the code for the document (a minimal version of that document) which is needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't get the formatting right. I've got double spaces after each line. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but pasting the code into the comment box just gives  
`\lyxformat 413  
\begin_document  
\begin_header  
\textclass article  
\language english  
\font_roman Futura Lt BT  
\font_sans default  
\font_typewriter default  
\font_default_family default  
\use_non_tex_fonts true  

\graphics default  
\end_header  

\begin_body  

\begin_layout Standard  
Test  
\end_layout  

\end_body  
\end_document`

Comment: Use the `edit` link at the  bottom left of your question. Paste the code. Hightlight and hit the `{}` button or ctrl+k.

Comment: I've tried to add it but I don't know what LyX code is supposed to look like, so you'll need to edit it. Code won't format properly in comments, though. (Other than for a very brief amount.) Works fine in questions, however. (Well, not quite fine, but it should be OK here.)

Comment: Sorry about that, I've got it formatted in the question now.

Comment: @ZackVacanti-Mitchell Can you please post a link to the file somewhere? I tried to copy/paste but my version of LyX says it is "malformed" so if you can  upload it somewhere that might be easier. Also, what version of LyX are you using? Note that the latest version is LyX 2.2.2.

Comment: [Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8_xkdlWB0KnQ29pMVFPNTRfS1k) This should bring up a link to the original file. I'm running version 2.0.8.1.

Comment: @ZackVacanti-Mitchell . I still get "Malformed LyX document" messages. However, I don't think that's the main cause of the problem. I'm not sure what the problem is. I don't know why LyX can find the font but LaTeX cannot. Perhaps check the permissions on the font files? Also, when you write a comment directed at someone, be sure to put the `@` followed by their name. Otherwise they might forget to check back.

Comment: @ZackVacanti-Mitchell I do not have 2.0.8.1, but a LyX developer who does have it opened and saved it and the saved file was different (and contained some missing parts). I'm worried your LyX installation might be corrupt. At the same time, I understand you might be hesitant to change to 2.2.2 because there is always a possibility that things that used to work for you no longer work.

Comment: @scottkosty No problem, I'll update later today when I get the chance and see try again.

Comment: @ZackVacanti-Mitchell OK but make sure you back everything up! That way you should always be able to go back to 2.0.8.1 if something goes wrong.

Comment: Installing the newest version of lyx and then configuring it for my system solved the problem. Thanks to scottkosty and cfr

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, an installation of an updated LyX version solved the problem. It's possible the previous installation was corrupt. Don't forget that whenever updating LyX, always back up your files.